# SQL file to PostgreSQl

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a MySQL database file (.sql) created a couple of years ago using MySQL Workbench. The database is approximately 600MB and contains blobs and DOBs (Date Objects). Now, I'm learning PostgreSQL and want to migrate this existing project to it. I'm aware of the general process of migrating a MySQL database to PostgreSQL, but I have specific concerns due to the size of the database and the presence of blobs and DOBs.

Is there any specific advice or considerations I should keep in mind while migrating a database of this size with blobs and DOBs from MySQL to PostgreSQL? Are there any recommended tools or approaches that can assist with the migration and ensure data integrity? Additionally, what are some potential challenges or differences between MySQL and PostgreSQL that I should be aware of during the migration process?

Comment: First step see [Migrate your mindset](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/).